# Virginia Woolf's "Orlando" sentence

Tags: grammar

Sentence

He-for there could be no doubt of his sex, though the fashion of the time did something to disguise it-was in the act of slicing at the head of a Moor which swung from the rafters.

What relation/meaning does sentence want to convey between "he" and the act of slicing.and what is a Moor.is it a head of Muslim/black man hanging on roof.and he is trying to slice it which gives away his gender/sex. i can't make sense of this. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that his sex was not in doubt is a parenthetical, and does not necessarily depend on anything in the rest of the sentence. It is saying that, although the fashion of the time made it harder to tell men from women, he was obviously male.

I'm confident, however, that you're right about what the "head of a Moor" is, here. It just has nothing to do with the characters maleness.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the sentence between dashes is in essence quite separate from the rest. It is the same as if it had been put in parentheses.

It is discussing the use of the male pronoun 'he', because Orlando changes gender in the course of the book. It has no relation to the main action of the sentence, which is Orlando 'slicing at the head of a Moor'.

A Moor is indeed an archaic word used for the Northern African Muslims who conquered the Iberian peninsula during the middle ages. By extension it came to refer to Arabs and sometimes Africans more generally.

The action of slicing at a Moor's head is not what reveals Orlando's gender, because it has already been stated that there can be 'no doubt' about his sex. I think the action is more about establishing Orlando's outrageous and swashbuckling nature.